# Rails Admin - Become Another User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm using Rails 3.0.10 and I'm currently using CanCan for determining the different abilities that users have within the application.

I am using Devise for the user authentication itself.

Is there a good way for an admin user to "become" another user temporarily using CanCan? This would be especially useful to become specific users who may be experiencing unique issues pertaining to their account.

So in simple terms, I just want to be able to sign in as any given user to see what they see. Not sure if there is a CanCan or Devise feature out there.

**UPDATE**

I just came across this:

[How-To: Sign in as another user if you are an Admin](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Sign-in-as-another-user-if-you-are-an-admin).

I haven't tested it yet, but it may be the answer I was looking for!! Feel free to provide some insight if this is the approach you took, or if you have another idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, and there's a gem for it!

[switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user)

It was really easy to use. I just have to add `gem switch_user` to my Gemfile.

Then add `<%= switch_user_select %>` to my layout. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

`CanCan` is authorization, you're interessted in authentification. If you're using anything based on `warden` (like `devise`), see [at the bottom.](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Users)
Make a scope (like `:admin`), where you store the admin user. Set the user you want to personify via `#set_user`. See link above.

Comment: I apologize for not giving enough information. I just updated my question. I am using Devise for user authentication, and CanCan for determining the abilities. In essence, I simply want the ability to sign in as another user to see what they see, but still have a button to return to the Admin Interface.

Answer (score 0):

If devise is irrelevant to what the user sees in your app, maybe you could do something along these lines:

1) create a new ability for your non-admin user

2) test if the user can do or see things

3) generate custom pages based upon these abilities

```
ability = Ability.new(@user)
Rails.logger.debug("* ability.can?(:update, @user):#{ability.can?(:update, @user)}") # see if user can access the user
Rails.logger.debug("* User.accessible_by(ability):#{User.accessible_by(ability).inspect.to_s}") # see if returns the records the user can access
Rails.logger.debug("* to_sql:#{User.accessible_by(ability).to_sql}") # see what the generated SQL looks like
```